# KSH Loop through num_machines In the below script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have to iterate

```
MACHINES_NUM=X


if [ "$MACHINES_NUM" = x ] 

then

    mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE1

    mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE2

fi



for i in $MACHINES_NUM

do

  mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE1/MACHINE$i

done
```

Comment: What is your question? And how is it different from your earlier one? All you have done is published some broken "code". Tell us what you want rather than what doesn't work.

Comment: I have to loop through the MACHINES_NUM value and create number of directories that come to MACHINES_NUM. @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
MACHINES_NUM=3
for i in $(seq $MACHINES_NUM)
do
   echo mkdir -p /something/$i
done
```

Remove the word `echo` if you like what it does and run it again.

**Output**

```
mkdir -p /something/1
mkdir -p /something/2
mkdir -p /something/3
```

Comment: Pleasure! Try typing `seq 4` into your terminal to see how it works.

Comment: hello Mark when I run the above script it gives me seq: missing operand
Try `seq --help' for more information. @Mark Setchell

Comment: You have changed from `ksh` to `sh` and completely changed your question after saying my answer worked...?

Comment: Hello Mark its sh I'm sorry for the wrong post @Mark Setchell

Comment: Mark please please help me @Mark Setchell

Comment: Use the code i gave you. It should work. Try typing `seq 3` and see if it prints 1 2 3 on 3 lines.